# Is there a nudist / FKK backpacker hostel anywhere in the world?

Tags: destinations, where-on-earth, hostels, nudism

So there are thousands of backpacker hostels in the world and there are many [FKK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freik%C3%B6rperkultur) beaches, resorts, and other accommodations designed for nudists in the world.

But has anyone yet opened a hostel for nudists anywhere?

Comment: Now I know the real reason why you've been traveling so much! You were on a quest, weren't you? :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Gazebo Golden Bay Backpackers](http://www.nakedbackpackers.com) in Takaka, New Zealand is clothing-optional, open December through March each year. Close to the nude beaches and a promoter of the local [Naked Bike Ride](http://www.pohara.co.nz/nakedbikeride). Quote: All levels of dress are acceptable.

Answer (score 11):

We have a location but not registered officially. Usually by invitation only as only want genuine nudists. We are in Western Australia. Genuine nudist backpackers can contact us via [BarelyBackpacking@hotmail.com](http://mailto:BarelyBackpacking@hotmail.com).

We do not tolerate drugs, we are not swingers, we are a family, our standing in the community is important and we don't want that jeopardised.

Comment: How do you determine they are 'genuine'?

Comment: [Pics or GTFO](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pics%20or%20gtfo). ;)

Answer (score 10):

<del>No, there are no nudist hostels, but</del> [Yes @user10134 has pointed to a clothes optional hostel] you can easily find some [nudist campsites in Europe](http://www.campings-in-europe.com/template_more_categories.php?category_id=10&type=main) or even some [nudist hotels](http://naturist-hotels.com/). Note that some naturist campsites only allow you to camp there if you are a couple to prevent voyeurs.

Comment: +1. By the way, here is an explanation why there might be no nude hostels ... http://nationallampoon.com/articles/nude-hostel

Comment: Hehe @lejohn that's why it might not work in the US. But maybe in Europe or Thailand or Mexico somewhere... (-:

Comment: Well, in Europe it would not be much different ...

Comment: Social nudity is about stuff including body acceptance, not about perving at each others' bums by the way. So the ages and attractiveness of guests shouldn't be a factor at all.